# Is there a workaround for Packages Comment and Sagetex incompatibility?

Tags: packages, incompatibility, comments, sagetex

I use the "Comment package" to write exercises with or without solutions. But I also want to use the "Sagetex package" to write the solution without typos. There seems to be an incompatibility between the Comment package and the Sagetex one. I get the following cryptic message: 
"Bad space factor (0). \end{comment}"
What does the message mean and is there a way to workaround this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}`
\usepackage{sagetex}`
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
This sentence
\begin{comment}
has
\end{comment}
no verb.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The packages should be loaded in reverse order:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{comment}
 \usepackage{sagetex}

 \begin{document}
 This sentence
 \begin{comment}
 has
 \end{comment}
 no verb.
 \end{document}
```

In any case the conditional compilation with a declared environment:

```
\includecomment{thisone}
\excludecomment{notthisone}
```

works whatever the loading order of the two packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment} %allows conditional compilation
\usepackage{sagetex}%For computing with SAGE within the text
\includecomment{thisone}
\excludecomment{notthisone}

\begin{document}
This sentence
\begin{comment}
has
\end{comment}
no verb.
Check for\begin{notthisone}
superfluous
\end{notthisone}
spaces and around
\begin{thisone}
inclusion
\end{thisone}
of proper texts.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember to mark your own answer as accepted.